# Laravel: Enforce unique rule if userid is different

Tags: php, laravel

I am working on a unique form validation rule on Laravel 5.4.

I have a list of items with userid tagged to them, each user items must be unique (name).

The only thing I have founf online is how to ignore the id, which is the opposite of what I need.

Answer (score 0):

```
unique:tbl_user_categories,name,NULL,name,user_id,'.$user_id,
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :-)
Please look at [answer]. You should provide some information why your code solves the problem.
Code-only answers aren't useful for the community.